ошибка: import discord_components( cannot import name 'InvalidArgument' from 'discord')
await ctx.send(embed = emb, components = [row]) строчка на которой возникает ошибка
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Need Programm\Python\botDiscord.py", line 11, in <module>
    import discord_components
  File "C:\Need Programm\Python\Lib\site-packages\discord_components\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client import *
  File "C:\Need Programm\Python\Lib\site-packages\discord_components\client.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .component import Component
  File "C:\Need Programm\Python\Lib\site-packages\discord_components\component.py", line 3, in <module>
    from discord import PartialEmoji, Emoji, InvalidArgument
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidArgument' from 'discord' (C:\Need Programm\Python\Lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py)

Источник ошибки, очевидно, находится в строчке import discord_components
Ошибка является результатом решения невозможности ввода pip install discord_components ручной установкой библиотеки в Lib\site-packages c гитхаба https://github.com/nike242/discord-components c помощью https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home (git+ для меня не сработало).

Решением моей проблемы стал отказ от discord_components, поскольку он был очень странным и код который я позаимствовал не сходился с действительными внутренностями библиотеки, если кому то тоже понадобилось создать сообщение с кнопкой, но вы не могли найти рабочий вариант: https://qna.habr.com/q/1161908?ysclid=lvphznet6t760637189, хотя там тоже плоховато но хотя бы с этим можно работать, если у вас есть понятные новичку рабочие предложения, прошу добавить
